# How to use wireshark analysis the tls packet Encrypted Alert in Ubuntu22.04

Tags: client-server, tls1.2, wireshark, ubuntu-22.04

I have a openssl project that is changed somewhere to use,so I develop a client and server in C++ which use the openssl library to perform a TLS handshake,and they will transport a string to each other after the TLS handshake is performed,and now it can transport successfully,but when I use the wireshark to see the packet and it shows two encrypted alert,I want to know why this happens and I want to decrypt the packet to know what is the specific alert information in this encrypted encrypted alert package.
the wireshark's packet information is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RNEb.png)
Because the server and client is my own code,so it is different with the analysis used to decrypt packet in Chrome packet analysis.
My server use three file:server.key,server.cert,and because i use pre-generated DH parameters,so i also have a file like dhparam.pem.
All of them are in the directory cert.They are like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ7a5.png)
I learned that someone said change the wireshark like this can decrypt the TLS,I did like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgzh9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulCO.png)
But it didn't work,I hope some one can answer my question does this encrypted alert will be something like close notify.and someone can tell me how to decrypt the packet in my situation.
Really thanks!